# su: Cannot make/remove an entry for the specified session

Tags: 16.04, sudo, authentication, pam

When im trying to do "sudo su -" in my ubuntu 16.04.6 server getting following error. I done few changes in pam.d config files.

```
Error - su: Cannot make/remove an entry for the specified session
```

If anyone can help me out its really appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's going to be hard to help without knowing what changes you made exactly to the PAM configurations - see for example [What does “Cannot make/remove an entry for the specified session” mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152098/what-does-cannot-make-remove-an-entry-for-the-specified-session-mean)

Answer (score 0):

Try using just su without the "sudo".

You need to be very careful with pam.d and pam.conf as you can lock yourself out of your own system if you make a mistake....as you have almost done.

If you cannot fix things up with su, and you have important data on your server that you cannot access, then try with Ubuntu live usb. You may be better off with a fresh installation after retrieving important data. Here you should install Ubuntu server 18.04. I can think of no good reason to be running old software.

Comment: I can access the server but cannot switch to the root user. I can do everything by using "sudo". Using "su" wasn't working and I have tired to restored original common-auth & common-password file but that attempt also failed.